# GCE Snapshot is taking too much time to create

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created a snapshot from one of my disk, but it never ends. I did it more than two hours ago. I cannot stop it, nor can I create a VM with that disk because it is being used:

**ERROR: RESOURCE_IN_USE: The disk resource 'projects/quoners-gce/zones/europe-west1-b/disks/development' is already being
 used in locked mode**
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+----------------+
| name                                                    | status | insert-time                   | operation-type |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+----------------+
| operation-1407932305607-50081c8f18958-728e2ec1-ded79090 | DONE   | 2014-08-13T05:18:25.942-07:00 | insert         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+--------+-------------------------------+----------------+

Is there anyway to stop that command?
In a previous answer I've seen someone from google that there was a problem on europe-west1-b but it has been fixed. It seem it hasn't :-(

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It finally finished. It took exactly 3 hours. Don't know if somebody at google did something.